# Getting state data into a table react

Tags: reactjs, antd

I've been stuck on this for 2hrs now and I think I'm thinking too hard, please help me simplify it. I want to return a table of information that I'm getting from my backend, so far, this is working perfectly but it's not a table:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

 class Pilot extends Component {
  render() {
  const { token, pilos } = this.props

  if(!token) return <Redirect to='/' />
  return (

  <div>
    {pilos.map(pilo => {
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{pilo.CreatedAt}</p>
          <p>{pilo.UpdatedAt}</p>
          <hr />
        </div>
      );
    })}
  </div>
)
 }
 }


 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
token: state.auth.token,
pilos: state.pilo.pilos
   }
   }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Pilo)
```

I am using Antd for my design, and I want to use [this](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-basic) design for my table. Any thoughts? I just can't get this information to render as a table and it's annoying me.

Comment: What is the payload your getting from the back end?

Comment: Maybe just a typo when you were writing the question, but in the last line(the export), shouldn't you have `Pilot` instead of `Pilo`. Did you check if you are getting the data in the component(console.log)? Also you won't get a table, when you're rendering just divs and paragraphs. It's not really obvious what's working and what's not and what is the question.

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem, if you want to render data in a table format then the rational thing to do is to use an HTML table tag.

Comment: @jdc91 it's an array of pilos.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj the code is working, I just need to put the information in a table format.

Comment: @LindaKadz If you figure out the answer please state the answer and mark it as answered. And also no body other than you know what pilos is, it would be better if you can clarify and mention it.

Answer (score 0):

So since you haven't provided a payload I'm going to continue with the fields you have provided.

```
import { Table, Divider, Tag } from 'antd';

class Pilot extends Component {
    render() {
        const {
            token,
            pilos
        } = this.props
        // assumed data from back end
        const pilos = [{
          CreatedAt: Wed Mar 20 2019 18:24:19,
          UpdatedAt: Wed Mar 20 2019 18:24:19'
        }, {
          CreatedAt: Wed Mar 20 2019 18:24:19,
          UpdatedAt: Wed Mar 20 2019 18:24:19'
        }];

        //Next you need to transform the data to the form required by the antd table
        //Here we only have to set a key value, I'm setting the array's index, but if you have a unique ID per pilot you can set it here.
        //const pilosDataForAntdTable = pilos.map((pilo,index)=> pilo.key = index);


        //This is how the Transformed data for the table will look like
        //Including the plain structure for clarity
        // You can remove this structure and uncomment the above map function
        const pilosDataForAntdTable = [{
          key: '1',
          CreatedAt: Wed Mar 20 2019 18:24:19,
          UpdatedAt: Wed Mar 20 2019 18:24:19'
        }, {
          key: '2',
          CreatedAt: Wed Mar 20 2019 18:24:19,
          UpdatedAt: Wed Mar 20 2019 18:24:19'
        }];

        // You have to define the columns here
        // It is important that you map the 'dataIndex' to the relevant field name
        // in [dataIndex: 'CreatedAt', CreatedAt: Wed Mar 20 2019 18:24:19] ==> The CreatedAt names are mapped together
        // This is how each cell is mapped to the column
        //You have to include the rest of the column names
        const columns = [{
          title: 'Created At',
          dataIndex: 'CreatedAt',
          key: 'CreatedAt',
        }, {
          title: 'Updated At',
          dataIndex: 'UpdatedAt',
          key: 'UpdatedAt',
        }];

        if (!token) return <Redirect to = '/' / >;
        return (
           <div>
               <Table dataSource={pilosDataForAntdTable} columns={columns} />
           </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: when I say `const { pilos, auth } = this.props` , the pilos are an array of pilos.